# Fade in Title using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein

I have the following HTML:

```
      <div id="header">
         <div id="logo_title">
            <p> What's Playing? </p>
         </div>
    </div>
```

I want to  make this fade in slowly when a user first visits the website. I'm using the following javascript:

```
  $(window).load(function () {
     $("#header").fadeIn(10000); 
   });
```

Here's the CSS:

```
      #logo_title, #logo_subtitle{
         height: 45px;
         font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
         font-weight: 300;
         font-size: 80px; 
         z-index: 4;
         text-align: center;
         margin: 100px 0px 0 0;
     line-height: 75px;
    }
```

It doesn't seem to be working though. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong? I'm new at this!

Thanks!

Comment: (1) Do you load jQuery? (2) Are you sure you're waiting long enough? 10 seconds is a long time. (3) Do you have any `<style>`s or stylesheets applied to this? If so, please post them.

Comment: Is `#header`'s CSS set to `display:none`? Use `$(document).ready` instead of `$(window).load`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start off by setting your `#header` to `display: none`, i.e.

```
 #header{display:none;}
```

then start the animation with

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#header").fadeIn(3000); 
   });
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eWB9H/).

Comment: I got it to work so that the title fades in. The next question is that there's a form on the page that takes in a value. When the user hits the submit button, the page refreshes so that the title now has to fade in again -- how do i prevent that from fading in again. In other words, the only time the title should fade in is the first time the user enters the webpage; everytime after, it should not.

Comment: You should post that as a separate question. There are a view strategies which allow you to achieve this - the simplest which may be to simply append a parameter to the form's querystring, and then based on it's value (or it being absent/present) you can conditionally perform the fade action.

Answer (score 5):

1. All jQuery animations that change an element’s `display` to or from `none` don’t take effect if the element is already in that state. You’ll need to hide it first.

   ```
   $("#header").hide().fadeIn(10000);
   ```
2. Use `$(document).ready`, not `$(window).load`. In fact, you may want to eschew the variety of events in favour of putting the `<script>` block directly beneath the header element to minimize FOUC. Of course, that’s not necessary when you can…
3. Accomplish this with CSS. (You might need to duplicate each of these with a `-webkit-` prefix, too.)

   ```css
   @keyframes fade-in {
       from { opacity: 0; }
       to { opacity: 1; }
   }

   #header {
       animation: fade-in 10s linear;
   }
   ```
4. That seems like a bit of an annoying animation. Are you *sure* it’s necessary?
5. This is just a guess, but you could maybe use more descriptive HTML:

   ```
   <header id="header">
       <h1 id="title">What’s Playing?</h1>
   </header>
   ```